# "Ізюм" чи "родзинки"?

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм

Завжди думала, що **ізюм** - це росіянізм і дуже здивувалась, коли знайшла у СУМі]2 словникові статті: [ізюм](http://sum.in.ua/s/izjum) і [родзинки](http://sum.in.ua/s/rodzynky). Ці слова знаходжу як синоніми у [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%86%D0%B7%D1%8E%D0%BC). 
Також знайшла у праці [Секрети української мови. Святослав Караванський](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Sekrety_ukrainskoi_movy/):

> Питома українська форма - **родзинки**,     російська форма-    **изюм** ,    Накинута форма - **ізюм**
>
> Отже, **ізюм** -це росіянізм? Якщо ні, то яке його походження і чи відрізняється воно за значенням від **родзинок**?

Answer (score 2):

Цікаво, що слово "родзинки" - це [полонізм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) (від. пол. "rodzynki"), а от слово "ізюм" потрапило до нашої мови з тюркської ("uzum").

Отож, як бачите і перше і друге слово є запозиченими, але можна вживати спокійно їх обидва, так як потрапили вони у нашу мову давно і вже встигли в ній вкорінитися. Доказами цього є те, що ми зустрічаємо їх у СУМі, як ви й написали. За значенням ("сушені ягоди винограду") ці слова також ніяк не відрізняються.

В Гугл перекладачі, якщо перекласти, наприклад, російське "изюм", то отримаємо як варіант "ізюм", так і варіант "родзинки".

Comment: Краще не використовувати гугл-перекладач для підтвердження або спростування лінгвістичної інформації. По-перше він був створений для того щоб замінити лінгвістичний підхід статистичним (але це не дуже спрацювало). По-друге - переклад з мови на мову використовує англійську як проміжний етап (тобто під час перекладу з російської на українську на справді текст спочатку перекладається на англійську, потім з англійської - на українську). По-третє, якщо слова гугл не знає, він його транслітерує. Неіснуюче слово "изьюменга" (рос.) стає "ізюменга" (укр.) або навіть scud (анг.) або izyumenga (анг.)

Comment: @Artemix, «під час перекладу з російської на українську на справді текст спочатку перекладається на англійську, потім з англійської - на українську» — здається, вже ні, але з іншим згоден: Google Перекладач — абсолютно не доказ, там будь-яка маячня може наводитися (зокрема користувачі можуть пропонувати власні варіанти (іноді безграмотні або створені заради жарту)).